# Decrease spacing between a bullet point and its subbullet point

Tags: spacing

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Cluster Middleware}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%% Decrease space here %%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item{Designed a cluster middleware for distributed processing and storage, being fault tolerant}
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

This is how it looks:
[image: ss]
Is there a way to change this spacing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us (a) which document class you employ and (b) whether you load packages, such as `enumitem` and `enumerate`, that can influence how `itemize` environments are displayed.

Comment: @Mico I have added the info in the question, do tell me if there is anything else missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `topsep` length of the sub-itemization can be changed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Cluster Middleware}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%% Decrease space here %%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=-5pt]
            \item{Designed a cluster middleware for distributed processing and storage, being fault tolerant}
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean decreasing the horizontal and the vertical spacing, here you are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{label=$\circ$, wide= 0pt, nosep, itemsep=2pt}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

    \item \textbf{Cluster Middleware}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%% Decrease space here %%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Designed a cluster middleware for distributed processing and storage, being fault tolerant
        \end{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Park EZ}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A smart parking appt which helps in finding and booking a parking spot.
            \item Updates the user in real time about the status of the parking spot using ultrasonic sensors.
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]